# Best way to switch USB power

Tags: mosfet, switching, usb-device, ldo

I'm looking for a way to switch an USB device's power (a [mini waterpump](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/flintronic-Wasserpumpe-Tauchpumpe-Aquarienpumpe-Aquarium/dp/B07TW39QXP/ref=sr_1_6?dchild=1&keywords=mini%20wasserpumpe&qid=1588797881&sr=8-6)) digitally. I've found some solutions, however I'm not sure what are the advantages/disadvantages of the different approaches, so I'd like to ask your opinions and which is the best to use.

Solution 1:
Using transistors similarly to this
[image]

Solution 2:
Using a 5V LDO with shutdown pin

Solution 3:
Using a dedicated USB power switch (e.g. [TPS203x](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps2032.pdf?&ts=1589242050756))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the device has the USB plug just for power input.

The circuit in option-1 looks okay. I don't know if the schematic generator automatically puts a name of "AOP605" on MOSFETs but make sure you select an N-Ch MOSFET for M1 and a P-Channel MOSFET for M2. Ones having a Vbrdss of 10V (min) and an Rds of 100-150mOhm (max) would do the job.

Using an LDO /w EN pin may simplify the circuit but the output voltage is the thing to consider. A USB port's voltage can be as low as 4.75VDC or can be as high as 5.25VDC. So the output of the LDO should be around 4.5VDC (The label on the product says that the input voltage can be as low as 3.5VDC so 4.5VDC won't harm it) which means you should use an adjustable type LDO.

Most of the load switch ICs have a current limiter mechanism inside. Some of them also have FAULT output (thermal or overcurrent). The ones with 1A current limit would do the job. They also simplify the circuit.

Comment: Thanks! And is there any meaningful difference in terms of power dissipation/consumption?

Comment: @Razero sorry, I was on mobile and I mistyped. And I revised my comment: For Option-1 and and -3 the consumption depends on the MOSFETs Rds and load current (from I²R). For Option-2, it depends on the USB port's output voltage as the dissipation is proportional to the difference (i.e. I × (VUSB - 4.5V)). Option-2 is the worst of course, especially when the port voltage is 5.25V, but the levels are not that high to worry about. Personally, I'd go for Option-2 or -3. Especially the TPS203x has a MOSFET with a very low Rds.

Comment: Can someone explain why you need two MOSFETs for option 1? Is it possible to do using a single MOSFET?

Comment: @Gerrit A PMOS having its source tied to 5V. So if we apply 3.3V to its gate to turn it off it still might be on as the Vgs becomes -1.7V which can be still below the threshold. Some MOSFETs have a threshold as low as -0.8V. So it's better to use a pre-driver. Or if the logic levels were same (i.e. 5V) the NMOS pre-driver wouldn't be needed.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation! FWIW, I came across this same schematic that has IRFU024N for M1 and IRF7416 for M2: https://www.testdevlab.com/blog/how-to-create-programmatically-switchable-usb-hub